# PostGIS st_intersects() and spatial index

Tags: performance, postgis, spatial-index

I have huge troubles understanding the usage of indexes 
by PosrgreSQL/PostGIS.

I have two spatial datasets: building outlines and flood polygons.
There are 4.700 flood polygons that are quite complex (many vertices) and 1.100.000 building outlines. I import them into the database using QGIS.

The geometry type of both datasets is POLYGON and SRID is also set to the same number.

I have built spatial indexes on both datasets:

```
CREATE INDEX ON outlines USING gist (geom)
CREATE INDEX ON flood USING gist (geom);
CLUSTER outlines USING outlines_geom_idx;
CLUSTER flood USING flood_geom_idx;
VACUUM ANALYZE outlines
VACUUM ANALYZE flood
```

I then run a simple query (only for 4000 outlines):

```
SELECT b.id, a.id FROM flood b, outlines a
WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id < 4000
```

I then used EXPLAIN ANALYZE on that query:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=79.68..17890.72 rows=21467 width=8) (actual 
time=28.817..10367.845 rows=46 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on outlines a  (cost=79.53..11103.17 rows=4013 
width=163) (actual time=0.366..7.821 rows=3999 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (id < 4000)"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=795"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ks_obrisi_mp_pkey  (cost=0.00..78.52             
rows=4013 width=0) (actual time=0.284..0.284 rows=3999 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (id < 4000)"
"  ->  Index Scan using flood_geom_idx on flood b  (cost=0.15..1.68 rows=1 
width=6161) (actual time=2.589..2.590 rows=0 loops=3999)"
"        Index Cond: (a.geom && geom)"
"        Filter: _st_intersects(a.geom, geom)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"Planning time: 1.735 ms"
"Execution time: 10368.131 ms"
```

But when I drop the index on flood dataset, query is much faster:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..431597.69 rows=21467 width=8) (actual 
time=42.442..4610.522 rows=46 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on flood b  (cost=0.00..1298.78 rows=9278 width=6161) (actual 
time=0.002..5.514 rows=9278 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using outlines_geom_idx on outlines a  (cost=0.29..46.37 
rows=1 
width=163) (actual time=0.459..0.490 rows=0 loops=9278)"
"        Index Cond: (geom && b.geom)"
"        Filter: ((id < 4000) AND _st_intersects(geom, b.geom))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 18"
"Planning time: 1.785 ms"
"Execution time: 4610.564 ms"
```

I see that the process of selection is totally different, and also that the
different index is used. Why this difference? I only found threads talking 
about index not improving query speed. In this case, spatial index reduces the speed by factor 2. Is it possible to tell planner which index to use?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `"Nested Loop  (cost=79.68..17890.72 rows=21467 width=8) (actual 
time=28.817..10367.845 rows=46 loops=1)"` That a gross over estimate of the number of rows. Probably the statistics on `id` are absent (or stale).

Comment: Paste the result of `\d flood` and `\d outlines`

Comment: `Column   |            Type             |                        Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('flood_id_seq'::regclass)
 geom       | geometry(MultiPolygon,3912) |
 objectid   | numeric                     |
 opn        | character varying(254)      |
 opn_opis   | character varying(254)      |
 se_anno_ca | character varying(254)      |
Indexes:
    "flood_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)`

Comment: `Column |            Type             |                         Modifiers
--------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer                     | not null default nextval('outlines_id_seq'::regclass)
 geom   | geometry(MultiPolygon,3912) |
 sid    | bigint                      |
Indexes:
    "outline_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "outlines_geom_idx" gist (geom) CLUSTER`

Comment: When I add the index to flood, the index is added in the end:    `"flood_geom_idx" gist (geom) CLUSTER`

Comment: UPDATE: if I cluster outlines by index on id, the query plan looks like this: `Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..6941.07 rows=20283 width=8) (actual time=334.256..10550.109 rows=46 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using outlines_idx on outlines a  (cost=0.43..209.25 rows=3761 width=163) (actual time=0.027..3.350 rows=3999 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id < 4000)`
 The rest  `->  Index Scan using flood_geom_idx... ` is the same and also the time needed for query is the same ~10s